# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - manifest empty or missing

Tags: javascript, json, push-notification, service-worker, google-app-engine-python

Im trying to implement push notification using Polymer. I followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/) and was able to get the service worker to be registered. I got the following comments of the Javascript console.

```
Service Worker is ready :^) ServiceWorkerRegistration
```

But I also received this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - manifest empty or missing
```

Note:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

is already in my index.html. Since Im using Google App Engine, in my app.yaml I have add the following as well

```
url: /manifest.json
  static_files: templates/manifest.json
  upload: templates/manifest.json
```

And if I try `localhost:8080/manifest.json`, my manifest json is displayed on the browser. Im unable to get it working. Please provide some help, suggestions to check if manifest.json is actually accessible in my index.html

Comment: Does it work in localhost? Can you add the contents of the manifest to the question?

Comment: No. The content is the same as that from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-05?hl=en , except for the sender id.

Comment: Are you serving the manifest with the Content-Type header set to `application/manifest+json`?

Comment: You should use `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` if your page is not located at the root of the website. Are you using HTTPS or localhost?